# CodeIgniter call Function in Class

Tags: php, codeigniter

Try to move a Codeigniter site to another hosting. To call a function in a Class I use http://example.com/publicdb/newdb/ncts_formular/ci/index.php/SendMail/sendMail. This is working. If I call the Function on my new server with https://www.example.com/apps/ncts_formular/ci/index.php/SendMail/sendMail
I get the error:

> Not Found: The requested URL /apps/ncts_formular/ci/index.php/SendMail/sendMail was not found on this server.

Where or what do I have to config`?

Comment: Is your new server properly configured? Is the `.htaccess` file there? It supports `.htaccess` and `modrewrite`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `$config['base_url']` is set to the new server's CodeIgniter root.

Another reason this can happen is if the controller file name does not begin with an uppercase letter. If the first server was a test site is on Windows but the live server is Apache this can bite you. Things will work on the testbed but not the new server.

The other thing to look at is `.htaccess`. Maybe the `rewritebase` option (if used) needs to be updated.

Comment: I've found the difference on the servers. The old server stores the site in /data the new server in /data/www. I'm not allowed to change server settings. Any solution?